# Why does MoveFile with same source and destination fail randomly?

Tags: c, winapi, file-rename

When I run the following simple C program on my Windows 7 system

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    int i;

    CreateDirectory("testdir", NULL);
    CreateDirectory("testdir\\foo", NULL);
    CreateDirectory("testdir\\bar", NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        BOOL result;

        result = MoveFile("testdir\\bar", "testdir\\foo\\bar");
        if (!result) {
            fprintf(stderr, "rename bar => foo/bar: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        result = MoveFile("testdir\\foo", "testdir\\foo");
        if (!result) {
            fprintf(stderr, "rename foo => foo: %d\n", GetLastError());
            fprintf(stderr, "after %d iterations\n", i);
            return 1;
        }

        result = MoveFile("testdir\\foo\\bar", "testdir\\bar");
        if (!result) {
            fprintf(stderr, "rename foo/bar => bar: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the call to `MoveFile("testdir\\foo", "testdir\\foo")` fails with error code 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`) after a random number of iterations:

```
C:\Users\nik>cl /O2 rename.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

rename.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:rename.exe
rename.obj

C:\Users\nik>rmdir /s /q testdir

C:\Users\nik>.\rename
rename foo => foo: 5
after 52 iterations

C:\Users\nik>rmdir /s /q testdir

C:\Users\nik>.\rename
rename foo => foo: 5
after 219 iterations

C:\Users\nik>rmdir /s /q testdir

C:\Users\nik>.\rename
rename foo => foo: 5
after 23 iterations
```

Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps it's your AV software. Easy enough to avoid this though. No point attempting to move A to A.

Comment: Just guessing: Could be that eventually you call `MoveFile()` while the file is still locked from the last time you called `MoveFile()` (might take a brief moment to be ready again)?

Comment: Random "in-use" errors are often caused by badly written* AV software (* all of them).

Comment: @JonathanPotter that issue has caused me endless hours of support with my app failing to start up due to the log file being "in use"

Comment: Try implementing a timeout by accessing and handling errors of MoveFile in a loop. Also, use ```rename``` from ```stdio``` if you are only after renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it's the Windows Search Service that causes the error. The solution is to exclude the folder via Indexing Options in Control Panel.